# CSS not applying in Github

Tags: html, css, github

I am making a website to host my games I have made and the CSS I made doesn't seem to be applying. the code is [here.](https://github.com/InfinityLoopGames/InfinityLoopGames.github.io)

I am a beginner at coding with HTML and CSS, so I just looked up different codes and tutorials and they didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS Code

```
background-image: linear-gradient((rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,150,0,0.5));
h1,p{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

is written in a wrong format, the way you have mentioned `background-image`
is wrong, it must be mentioned for a specific tag, if you want that background for the whole page the correct code is:

```
body{
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,150,0,0.5));
}
h1,p{
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And also you had added extra set of parenthesis `linear-gradiant`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first line of your style.css file.
you can't define css properties without specifying any selector, so it makes all your styles not work!
comment that line and see your styles apply or specify a selector for your background property